# How to run multiple redis instances with systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, redis, multiple-instances

I recently moved to Debian 8 "Jessie" which now use systemd and I can't find a way to run multiple redis instances.

I found out there is a `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service` file to start redis-server on reboot. So I created a new file call `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server-2.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Advanced key-value store
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis-2.conf
TimeoutStopSec=0
Restart=always
User=redis
Group=redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I try to start the service like this: `service redis-server-2 start` I get this error:

```
Job for redis-server-2.service failed. See 'systemctl status redis-server-2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

And `systemctl status redis-server-2.service` give me:

```
● redis-server-2.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server-2.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2015-10-10 11:09:54 CEST; 33s ago
  Process: 2473 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis-2.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2371 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 10 11:09:54 server101 systemd[1]: redis-server-2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 10 11:09:54 server101 systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
Oct 10 11:09:54 server101 systemd[1]: Unit redis-server-2.service entered failed state.
Oct 10 11:09:54 server101 systemd[1]: redis-server-2.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Oct 10 11:09:54 server101 systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
Oct 10 11:09:54 server101 systemd[1]: Unit redis-server-2.service entered failed state.
```

which is not really helping me.

But if I run `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis-2.conf` my redis instance start correctly.

So any idea why systemd don't what to start this instance by itself ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Damn, the answer was indeed in the syslog... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested by  Michael Hampton, I checked the syslog and found that:

```
Oct 10 11:33:46 server101 redis-server[1947]: *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Oct 10 11:33:46 server101 redis-server[1947]: Reading the configuration file, at line 5
Oct 10 11:33:46 server101 redis-server[1947]: >>> 'logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server-2.log'
Oct 10 11:33:46 server101 redis-server[1947]: Can't open the log file: Permission denied
```

So I just had to do this to fix the issue:

```
chown redis:redis /var/log/redis/redis-server-2.log
```